# Rails: How to store values dynamically or as cookie

Tags: cookies, ruby-on-rails-3.2

May be the question will sound weird. But as I am doing it very first time, don't know what is it exactly called.

I have a search method with typeahead used in it on homepage of www.mealnut.com (do check a live demo). There are two entries, city and category. City shows data in typeahead array and on submit, gives the search result. Here is a code:

```
 <%= form_tag search_path, :method => 'get' do %> 
    <%= text_field_tag 'search', nil, :placeholder =>"Enter your city ", :autocomplete => :off, :'data-provide' => "typeahead", :id=>"citysearch" %>
            <%= select_tag :category, options_from_collection_for_select(@categories, "id", "category", params[:category]), html_options = { :prompt => 'Select a category'} %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search"%>
<% end %>
```

And here is typeahead script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var cities = ["Bengaluru", "Pune", "New Delhi", "Delhi", "Mumbai"
$("input[data-provide='typeahead']").typeahead({source: cities});
});
```

And here is issue: when user clicks on back button to return on home page, city gets wiped out and category remains as selected. Here user should see city, he entered last time instead of blank field.

I think this happens cause typeahead just gives array and doesn't store value anywhere. I dont want to create separate table for array.

i found cookie might be the option. But dont know how to go with it as never tried cookie. Also, what is the best solution on this cookie or anything else? Has anybody done this?

Please help!

**Update:**

I used cookie for one city in controller. My home controller's index action is:

```
def index
 @categories = Category.all
 cookies[:search] = "Mumbai"
end
```

And modified index page form for search to:

```
 <%= text_field_tag 'search', nil, :placeholder =>"#{cookies[:search]} ", :autocomplete => :off, :'data-provide' => "typeahead", :id=>"citysearch" %>
```

This shows city Mumbai on back button click. But i dont want city to be fixed. It should be user entered value. Can anyone tell how to do it?